# Display custom taxonomy for product

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have to display custom taxonomy for every product which is i have selected for every product from back end.

I have created custom taxonomy `city` in that custom taxonomy i have added the `Nashik ,Mumbai` city.

In product page i have assigned custom taxonomy city  `Nashik` to that product that assigned city `Nashik` i have to display at product page.

i have tried out with bellow code but it's displaying the all city list like `Mumbai` `Nashik` here i have to display specific city name for product.

```
wp_tag_cloud( array( 'taxonomy' => 'city', format => 'list' ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [wp_tag_cloud](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud)
pls try this in product page

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'city' ); 
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'city' );
                        if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
                        continue;
                    echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                    } 
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late already but I think the [Woocommerce - Products By Custom Tax](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-by-custom-tax/) plugin should do what are you trying to achieve, I am the developer.

For your case the shortcode of the plugin would be like this:

```
[woo_products_custom_tax tax_name="city" tax_tags="nashik" columns="4"]
```

If you want to show more cities you can place them separated by a comma on the **tax_tags** attribute

```
[woo_products_custom_tax tax_name="city" tax_tags="nashik,mumbai" columns="4"]
```

Comment: All ready got the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created custom taxonomies in WordPress, the next step is to display them on post pages. Fortunately, this is a matter of adding the following single line of code to the single.php (located in the theme folder):

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, ‘topics’, ‘Topics: ‘, ‘, ‘, ‘ ‘ ); ?>
```

By default custom taxonomies use the archive.php template to display posts. However, you can create a custom archive display for custom taxonomies by creating taxonomy-{taxonomy-slug}.php,where taxonomy-slug refers to slug of custom taxonomy.

I found the solution at https://www.wpblog.com/create-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress/

Hope it will help you